# Android Key Hash - Users appearing to have different keys

Tags: android, facebook, hash, key, match

We've had our app out on Android for well over a year with facebook integration. I set up the key hash on the Facebook app when the build was first made.

We launched a new version of the game 2 days ago, and we have some users with the error:

> Invalid key hash <key hash> does not match any stored hash keys.

There are two completely different key hashes appearing in our logs, both from multiple users. Yet, the vast majority of users, including our handsets, have no problem and are using the correct key.

Nothing has been built differently, we're using the same production certificate as always.

I don't understand how the build could be producing completely different keys, as far as i'm aware, this isn't even possible?

Possibly something could be corrupt? Has anyone experienced this?

*UPDATE*

We've found that it is only affecting Kindle, not Google Play builds. Additionally, it only appears to affect users with the Facebook app installed.

Comment: Have you checked that the keystore and build keys are exactly the same as before? And are you using Play Store to distribute the app?

Comment: Yes, they are under version control, and I checked the version history on it, which shows no changes  since last year.

Additionally, I unzipped the production APK, grabbed the CERT.RSA file, used keytool to get the SHA1, then converted that, which produced the same key hash as on our facebook app.

We are on google play store, yes.

Comment: Here are the two key hashes that are appearing in our logs and on users screens:

Invalid key hash. The key hash AV1rljok/OSV+NRfm/jhuxm6/RM does not match any stored key hashes.

Invalid key hash. The key hash ufV5E7igoQorpEvYkIwlIAWfgB8 does not match any stored key hashes.

I've actually tried just adding them into our facebook app, but it won't accept either of them.

Comment: Is your app free or paid? Is there anything in the app to make it worth of cracking? I can't think of any other case other than somebody decompiled your app and then compiled it again with his own key and distributed it

Comment: It's free. yes, there are in app purchases which make it worth cracking. I did think of this as well actually. The only reason I wasn't going down that route is it has happened all of a sudden, on a build that was just released, and not before then.

Comment: yeah this makes sense, well I do not have other explanations, sorry

Comment: Thanks for trying :), I'm only asking here, because I've been through everything myself!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was identified as Kindle only users. We then found it only occurred when the Facebook app was installed. We recently updated to the GoViral ANE for Facebook Login, but hadn't released a new Kindle build until recently, which broke the Login for those users with the Facebook app installed (previously the app never used the Facebook app at all). After speaking with Amazon, they explained that they resign the APK, and provided us with the new hash. It's all working now.